# Deep Neural Networks using Tensorflow Leaky Relu giving accuracy 0 when changed from mnist dataset to csv read data file

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

My program is as below in jupyter, I took from one of the github repositories of deep computing code and changed as per my needs. The change is to change automatic download from mnist and working on dataset types to having a data file and then reading the data using pd.csv

I have printed data at each step before passing to training, each step looks to be fine but finally it gives accuracy as 0.

Program that works fine is as below:

```
# To support both python 2 and python 3
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals

# Common imports
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf

# to make this notebook's output stable across runs
def reset_graph(seed=42):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

reset_graph()

n_inputs = 28 * 28  # MNIST
n_hidden1 = 100
n_hidden2 = 100
n_outputs = 10

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name="y")

with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden1, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="hidden1")
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden2, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="hidden2")
    logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, n_outputs, name="outputs")

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

learning_rate = 0.01

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("data/")

type(mnist)

n_epochs = 1
batch_size = 50

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for iteration in range(mnist.train.num_examples // batch_size):
            X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            #if iteration == 0:
            print(X_batch)
            print(X_batch.shape)
            print(type(X_batch))
            print(y_batch)
            print(y_batch.shape)
            print(type(y_batch))
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: mnist.validation.images, y: mnist.validation.labels})
            print(epoch, "Batch accuracy:", acc_train, "Validation accuracy:", acc_test)
    w = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("hidden1/kernel:0").eval()
    print(w)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "model_ckps/my_model_final.ckpt")
```

Program that gives accuracy as 0 is as below:

```
# To support both python 2 and python 3
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals

# Common imports
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf

# to make this notebook's output stable across runs
def reset_graph(seed=42):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

reset_graph()

n_inputs = 28 * 28  # MNIST
n_hidden1 = 100
n_hidden2 = 100
n_outputs = 10

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name="y")

with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden1, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="hidden1")
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden2, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="hidden2")
    logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, n_outputs, name="outputs")

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

learning_rate = 0.01

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

csv = pd.read_csv("data/mnist-k-train.csv")

y_train = csv["label"]
X_train = csv.drop(labels = ["label"], axis=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X_train = X_train.astype(float)
X_val = X_val.astype(float)

X_train_size = len(X_train)

n_epochs = 1
batch_size = 50

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for iteration in range(X_train_size // batch_size):
            start = iteration * batch_size
            end = (iteration+1) * batch_size
            if(end > X_train_size):
                end = X_train_size
            X_batch = X_train.iloc[start:end, :].values
            y_batch = y_train.iloc[start:end].values
            #if iteration == 0:
            print(X_batch)
            print(X_batch.shape)
            print(type(X_batch))
            print(y_batch)
            print(y_batch.shape)
            print(type(y_batch))
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_val.values, y: y_val.values})
            print(epoch, "Batch accuracy:", acc_train, "Validation accuracy:", acc_test)
    w = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("hidden1/kernel:0").eval()
    print(w)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "model_ckps/my_model_final.ckpt")
```